# Material UI Slider - Place Labels Below Slider Track in React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, slider

I have a React project that I am required to create a Material UI Slider.  But it is placing the mark labels above the track and I need them to be below the track.  My code looks like the following:

```
const Timeline: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const marks = [
    {
      value: 0,
      label: "45",
    },
    {
      value: 15,
      label: "30",
    },
    {
      value: 30,
      label: "15",
    },
    {
      value: 45,
      label: "0",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <CustomCard containerClass={classes.container} border={false} variant="default">
      <Grid container direction="column" className={classes.contentContainer}>
        <Slider
          className={classes.slider}
          min={0}
          max={45}
          step={15}
          defaultValue={45}
          valueLabelDisplay="off"
          marks={marks}
          disabled
        />
      </Grid>
    </CustomCard>
  );
};

export default Timeline;
```

When I do this, I get the following Slider (The CSS makes it black with no thumb)

[image]

Any ideas how I can get the mark labels to be below the track??

Comment: By default, MUI slider marks should come in the bottom. The problem seems to be is non of the styles in MUI not appropriately applied here. Did you import the sliderModule to your module?

Comment: Yes.  I used the following - import { fade, Grid, makeStyles, Slider, Theme, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

Comment: Looks like buried deep in the project I was assigned to, they set a theme file in which they set Global CSS properties for sliders that was affecting them everywhere, and that is where they messed with it enough to get the text above the slider.  I was able to work it out from there.